# Right values as function argument, correct usage?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, rvalue-reference, stdmove

Trying to use rightvalues a bit more but I got confused, how should I design my function in which I want to use the right value:

```
// Pass by whatever-it's-called
void RockyBalboa::DoSomething(std::string&& str){ 
     m_fighters.push_back(str);
}
// Pass by reference
void RockyBalboa::DoSomething(std::string& str){
     m_fighters.push_back(std::move(str)); 
}
```

And what is effectively the difference between these two function calls? And what happens when I pass it with double ampersand *and* use `std::move` ?

Comment: Its the other way around, the `&&` one should be moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've swapped the usage. It's the [Rvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Rvalue_references) reference that can be moved. The [Lvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Lvalue_references) reference should be made `const`:

```
// Rvalue reference
void RockyBalboa::DoSomething(std::string&& str){ 
     m_fighters.push_back(std::move(str));
}
// Lvalue reference
void RockyBalboa::DoSomething(const std::string& str){ // note: const
     m_fighters.push_back(str);
}
```

You could however use a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) to cover both cases:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Forwarding reference
template<typename T>
void RockyBalboa::DoSomething(T&& str) {
    // Create a nice error message at compile time if the wrong type (T) is used:
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string>);

    m_fighters.emplace_back(std::forward<T>(str));
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I actually needed forward too because I have a wrapper function that does something like `wrapper(std::string&& str) { return g(std::string str) }` which I now changed to `return g(std::forward<std::string>(str))`

Comment: @dejoma Glad it helped! Please do read the link about forwarding references carefully - especially the part that says: "_Forwarding references are either: 1) function parameter of a function template declared as rvalue reference to cv-unqualified type template parameter of that same function template. 2) `auto&&` except when deduced from a brace-enclosed initializer list:_".